# How do i clear a multi-select input using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

How do i clear (deselect) all options within a multi-select input using Cypress?

The documentation here does not seem to cover this scenario: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Syntax

The `clear()` command apparently cannot be applied to selects, as you might expect
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clear.html#Syntax

I have tried passing an empty string / array / null to `select()` but i get the following error:

`CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because it could not find a single <option> with value or text matching: ''`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Cypress 8.6.0, this is supported in Cypress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69537449/3474615

---

Before 8.6.0:

You can use [`cy.invoke()`](https://on.cypress.io/invoke) to call the [`.val('')`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method on the underlying JQuery element, which will cause it to be cleared.

Like this:

```js
cy.get('select')
.invoke('val', '')
```

Note that this will not emit the `change` event. If you want to test that your code reacts to the `change` event, you can cause it to be emitted with [`cy.trigger()`](https://on.cypress.io/trigger):

```js
cy.get('select')
.invoke('val', '')
.trigger('change')
```

---

I've also [filed a feature request for this functionality](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4318), as it does seem like something that should be included with Cypress by default.

Comment: This has been added to v8.6.0 now

Answer (score 3):

```
cy.select([])
```

`cy.select([])` called with an empty array, can now be used to clear selections on all options.

Note: update cypress to [v8.6.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/releases/tag/v8.6.0) or higher to work.