# How to reset a field which is not a clearable in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

When I try to reset a field with cy.clear() and the element is a dropdown,
it is failed because it requires a valid clearable element.

`When('@userSettings.actions I reset Gender', () => { userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown().clear(); });`

Cypress gives the error as, /
`cy.clear() failed because it requires a valid clearable element.`

Comment: can you share your html dom on which you are trying this ?

Comment: I use cy.reload() for such cases but not sure it is applicable for your case

Comment: @AlapanDas - HTML DOM is herewith, 



<input aria-invalid="false" name="dateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd" value="">

Comment: @RosenMihaylov - yes cy.reload() won't be relevant clearing the fields, because it is for reloading without cache. But this is just clearing the input data on the field, thanks bdw. :)

Comment: @AlapanDas - 
This worked in clearing the values of a dropdown.

`userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown().invoke('val', ' ')`

Comment: @ Rashmi Sandarekha  My case was that cypress-file-upload was not clearing the file input after the first file i upload, and if I upload a second file in successsion it uploads 1+2. if third 1+2+3 and so on. So i started upload - save - reload - repeat. By the way if it is multy select - you should be able to find the subelements on which to do cy.uncheck()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [How do I clear a multi-select input using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340978/how-do-i-clear-a-multi-select-input-using-cypress).

There is usually an input underlying a dropdown, so possible suggestions you might use -

```js
userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown()
  .invoke('val', '')
  .trigger('change')

userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown()
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val', '')
  .trigger('change')
```

Some other suggestions floating around, but a little bit dubious -

```js
userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown()
  .type({selectall}{backspace})

userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown()
  .select([])
```

---

I notice in the Cypress test [clear_spec.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/cypress/integration/commands/actions/clear_spec.js)

```js
context('works on input type', () => {
  const inputTypes = [
    'date',
    'datetime',
    'datetime-local',
    'email',
    'month',
    'number',
    'password',
    'search',
    'tel',
    'text',
    'time',
    'url',
    'week',
  ]

  inputTypes.forEach((type) => {
    it(type, () => {
      cy.get(`#${type}-with-value`).clear().then(($input) => {
        expect($input.val()).to.equal('')
      })
    })
  })
})
```

which is a pretty long list of valid types, so if you do have an input behind the form control this might be all you need

```js
userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown()
  .find('input')
  .clear()
```

Comment: Yes this works in below way.
``userSettings.form.getGenderDropdown().invoke('val', ' ')``

Answer (score 1):

This snippet does the job. Please learn it and try to modify it for you. I selected one of the available options, then deleted 'disabled' atrribute from the default option to select it in future.

```
it('example', function () {
    cy.visit('https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-select-dropdown-demo.html');
    cy.get('[id="select-demo"]').select('Monday')
    cy.get('[id="select-demo"]').find('option').eq(0).then(($elem) => {
        $elem.removeAttr('disabled')
    })
    cy.get('[id="select-demo"]').select('Please select')
})
```

Comment: Technically it's not a reset, the value ends as an empty string where-as the initial value upon load is null.

Comment: Yes I was looking for clearing the input data of a field and for the text fields or text areas the `cy.clear()` work. But for the dropdowns, the `cy.invoke()` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reset the form, presuming clearing the whole form is what you are aiming for.

Please see [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

> The HTMLFormElement.reset() method restores a form element's default values. This method does the same thing as clicking the form's reset button.
>
> If a form control (such as a reset button) has a name or id of reset it will mask the form's reset method. It does not reset other attributes in the input, such as disabled.

**HTML**

```html
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="select-demo">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**Test**

```js
it('resets the form values', () => {

  cy.get('select').should('have.value', null);         // starts with empty value

  cy.get('select').select('Female')                    // select an option
    .should('have.value', 'Female');                   

  cy.get('form').then($element => $element[0].reset())

  cy.get('select').should('have.value', null);         // now empty again

})
```

Comment: Resetting it based on the element doesn't seem to work, I am trying to reset the form using the HTML element reset() but it is not recognized (but it recognizes submit())